# unable to override a ribbon boarder color

Tags: css, master-pages, page-layout

I have a ribbon inside SharePoint server 2013 with a green border, as shown below:-
[image]

The ribbon has three css classes , and inside my custom CSS, i define the following CSS rules:-

```
.ms-cui-tabContainer ms-cui-tabContainer-gr  {
    border-color:#008CD2 !important;
}
.ms-cui-tabBody ms-cui-tabBody-gr{
    border-color:#008CD2 !important;

}
.ms-cui-ribbon{
    border-color:#008CD2 !important;
}
```

but the ribbon still has a green border instead of a #008CD2 blue border. Can anyone give me advice please?

**EDIT**

The full marup under the ms-cui-RibbonTopBars

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working :

```
.ms-cui-tabBody.ms-cui-tabBody-gr{
    border-color:#008CD2 !important;
}
.ms-cui-tabContainer.ms-cui-tabContainer-gr  {
    border-color:#008CD2 !important;
}
```

Comment: this has chnaged the boarder color for the bottom boarder only. although i have updated my CSS with the folloiwng  .ms-cui-tabBody.ms-cui-tabBody-gr{
    border-color:#008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 #008CD2 !important;
border-top-color:#008CD2 !important;
}

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did so but still the uppoer boarder is green? can you adivce on this please?

Comment: have you tried to add `ms-cui-ribbonTopBars{border-color:#008CD2 !important;}`

Comment: i added it but nothing was changed , still the upper boarder is green?

Comment: can you show what's in <div class="ms-cui-ribbonTopBars" unselectable="on">

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have added a picture showing what is under the ms-cui-ribbonTopBard , in my original post.

Comment: yeah you should try to add border-color to children of ms-cui-ribbonTopBard like ms-cui-TopBar2, ms-cui-TopBarMaximized, ms-cui-ct-topBar-gr (to do test and see which div need to be changed, add border-color to element.style in firefox)